# LINQ SelectMany equivalent in Scala

Tags: linq, scala

I have some quite simple .NET logic that I'm transplanting into a Scala codebase, and I don't really know the first thing about Scala. It includes a LINQ query that groups a collection of tagged objects by making use of an anonymous type projection to flatten and join, followed by grouping, eg:

```
var q = things.SelectMany(t => t.Tags, (t, tag) => new { Thing = t, Tag = tag })
              .GroupBy(x => x.Tag, x => x.Thing);
```

In Scala it looks like `flatMap` might be of use, but I can't figure out how to combine it with `groupBy` via an anonymous.

Is this kind of thing a lot more complicated in Scala, or am I missing something simple?

UPDATE:

I ended up going with:

```
things.flatMap(t => t.Tags.map(x => (x,t))).groupBy(x => x._1)
```

and then of course later on when I access a value in the map I need to do:

```
.map(x => x._2)
```

to get the groups out of the tuple.

Simple when you know how!

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you want to accomplish, can you correct your C# example. SelectMany only takes one input (other than the extension `this` parameter) and you seem to have two. Also your parentheses are not balanced and its confusing to figure out where you intended them to go.

Comment: I see you added the missing parenthesis but your `SelectMany` has too many arguments a source and a selector method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx but you seems to be providing two methods

Comment: Sorry, missed a parenth.

Comment: @Danny - There is a [matching overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549142(v=vs.110).aspx) of `SelectMany`.

Comment: The second arg is the result selector

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you want to do something like.

```
case class Tag(tag:String)

case class Thing(Tags : Seq[Tag])

val things :Seq[Thing] = Seq(Thing(Seq(Tag(""))))

val q = things.map {
  thing => new {
    val Thing = thing
    val Tags = thing.Tags
  }
}.flatMap {
  thingAndTags => thingAndTags.Tags.map {
    tag => new {
      val Thing = thingAndTags.Thing
      val Tag = tag
    }
  }
}. groupBy {
  thingAndTag => thingAndTag.Tag
}.map {
  tagAndSeqOfThingAndTags =>
    tagAndSeqOfThingAndTags._1 -> tagAndSeqOfThingAndTags._2.map(x => x.Thing)
}
```

But in Scala anonymous objects are not really common but you can use `Tuple2[T1,T2]` instead of all the `new { val ...}`s,

```
val q = things.map {
  thing => ( thing->thing.Tags)
}.flatMap {
  thingAndTags => thingAndTags._2.map {
    tag => (thingAndTags._1, tag)
  }
}.groupBy {
  thingAndTag => thingAndTag._2
}.map {
  tagAndSeqOfThingAndTags =>
    tagAndSeqOfThingAndTags._1 -> tagAndSeqOfThingAndTags._2.map(x => x._1)
}
```

its just a little confusing with all the `._1`s and `._2`s

Comment: thanks. I did end up going with the tuple. The missing piece in Scala is the ability to provide a result/element selector, I think, but it's still very concise.

Comment: @lesscode if you really want you can create "overrides" for the `flatmap` and `groupby` methods by using implicit conversion from Seq to "RichSeq" (or whatever you wanna name it) so your code can look more like the C# equivalent